# css inside gridview not showing after ajaxupdate

Tags: ajax, css, yii, cgridview

inside a `gridview` i have a css based inline graph. everything is working fine untill i filter something and the gridview gets updated. then css is not registering inside the grid anymore. anyone knows a solution? to be honest i don't even know what to try in this situation. css is not one of my strong points.

---

this is the element before ajaxupdate:

[image: this is the element before ajaxupdate]

---

This is after the ajax update

[image]

```
.stat-block .stat-graph {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #D7D7D7;
border-radius: 3px;
margin-right: 10px;
padding: 10px 10px 8px;
text-align: center;
width: auto;
```

}

as far as i can see first time the grid is generated css generates a canvas tag like so

```
<canvas style="display: inline-block; width: 29px; height: 20px; vertical-align: top;" width="29" height="20"></canvas>
```

but after the ajax update and the refresh of the gridview that tag won't appear anymore.

i have tried to put the graph data inside the canvas tag whit no success.

here is the gridview code:

```
this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' => 'cartuse-grid',
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
'filter' => $model,
'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'reinstallDatePicker',
'columns' => array(
    array(
        'id' => 'autoId',
        'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
        'selectableRows' => '50',
    ),
    //  'id',
    array(
        'name'=>'client',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'value'=>'client($data->client)',
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'align'=>'center',
            //'width'=>'35%'
        )
```

here is the client function:

```
       function client($client)   {     

...

return '<div class="stat-block" id="graph">
            <ul>
                <li class="stat-graph inlinebar" id="activitate-lunara">
                '.$data.'
                </li>
                <li class="stat-count">
                    <span>'.$data['0'].'
                    </span>       
                </li> 
                <li class="stat-percent">
                    <span class="text-info stat-percent">'.$target.'</span>
                </li>               
            </ul>
        </div>';
}
```

**Edit 1 :**
as recomended in answer 1 i used the [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) functions to refresh css after ajax update. nothing hapens, the canvas tag still won't appear.

i tryed to use [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) and just insert the canvas tag that way but then it will brake the filtering.

here's the reinstallDatePicker function

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('re-install-date-picker', "
function reinstallDatePicker(id, data) {
   $('#datepicker_min').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                                      showOtherMonths: true,
                                      selectOtherMonths: true,
                                      changeYear: true,
                                      changeMonth: true,
                                      });
   $('#datepicker_max').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                                      showOtherMonths: true,
                                      selectOtherMonths: true,
                                      changeYear: true,
                                      changeMonth: true,
                                      });
   $( \"#activitate-lunara\" ).removeClass( \"stat-graph inlinebar\" );
   $( \"#graph\" ).removeClass( \"stat-block\" );
   $( \"#graph\" ).addClass( \"stat-block\" );
   $( \"#activitate-lunara\" ).addClass( \"stat-graph inlinebar\" );

}"); ?>
```

**Edit 2:**

i wasn't using renderPartial as column content. just a function that returned the content i wanted. after exhausting All posible ideeas i moved to renderpartial and with renderpartial + registering scripts / css in the partialview and removeclass / addclass everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this issue sometimes as well.

First thing: If you're using partial views, include the CSS in the partial view as well.

If not, you will probably have to re-apply the style after each ajax update.

I see that you are using `"afterAjaxUpdate"=>"reinstallDatePicker"` so one way to fix your problem is to add that CSS to `.stat-block .stat-graph` inside that function. You can use jquery functions like [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/), [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and many others.

But the important thing is that you style your elements after each ajax update. Since your function `reinstallDatePicker` is being called after each ajax update, you can just add some code to this function to do what you want (that is, re-style the elements).

Answer (score 0):

i have tried everything i can think of without success. the only way i could get it to work was to store my filter data in my session and then afterajaxupdate force a reload. (not really recommended because if your query's are not optimized i guess it could slow down your page)

i'm just posting this here in case someone else has this problem and want to get it working before someone else finds a correct solution

so now in my controller i have this

```
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new Cartuse('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Cartuse']))
                $_SESSION['filterData'][$this->id][$this->action->id] = $_GET['Cartuse'];
                $model->attributes=$_SESSION['filterData'][$this->id][$this->action->id];
    if (isset($_GET['pageSize'])) {
        Yii::app()->user->setState('pageSize',(int)$_GET['pageSize']);
        unset($_GET['pageSize']);
    }
    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

and in my gridview

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'cartuse-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'reinstallDatePicker',
    'columns' => array(/*
            .....
        )
));
```

and the reinstall datepicker (for some reason if i put the location.reload () directly in the afterajaxupdate field my datepickers won't register (not even first time) and filtering stops working. so i put it in the reinstalldatepicker function. no problems till now.

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('re-install-date-picker', "
    function reinstallDatePicker(id, data) {
            location.reload();
       $('#datepicker_min').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                                          showOtherMonths: true,
                                          selectOtherMonths: true,
                                          changeYear: true,
                                          changeMonth: true,
                                          });
       $('#datepicker_max').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                                          showOtherMonths: true,
                                          selectOtherMonths: true,
                                          changeYear: true,
                                          changeMonth: true,
                                          });
       $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ro']);
     }
");
```

this is not really a solution, its jut a cheap workaround so if anyone has a solution i'll be waiting for it.